# isTrigger not disabling physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2d collider that is just a trigger and doesn't have any collision, but even when the collider has isTrigger checked, my character is still colliding with the box. I am using the "@D Platformer Controller" asset, so maybe there is something in there that is messing with things, but regardless, I don't know what is wrong. Any ideas on what I can check?: Thanks.

Comment: Does the game object have multiple Collider2Ds attached to it?

Comment: How does the "2D Platformer Controller" asset work? Does it use Unity's `rigidbody2d` for movement? If not, their movement implementation could just completely ignore `IsTrigger`.

Comment: I will have to look. Thanks for the guidance I will let you know.

Comment: It uses ray casting and not a rigid body, so the problem lies in that. Thanks all for the guidance.